# Google Play Console - can't edit a draft

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

I opened an account in google play console, and I started a draft for a new app.
I didn't finish the draft and I exited it.
Now I logged back in to google play console, but I don't see any place to continue edit the draft.

[image: This is what I see on console]

So as far as I can see I can only delete it, I've searched for all their menu but didn't see anywhere to edit it.

any suggestions?

**EDIT**:
when I click the app name I get redirected to the release page which contains only this:
[Release page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1zV9.png)

Comment: Did you try clicking on the app name? That should open it, and you can there proceed with the release.

Comment: @Pierre please see my edit

Comment: You should have on the left hand side a menu to navigate to different sections of the website which should allow you to upload an APK or Android App Bundle, to configure your page listing, etc.

Comment: simply click on app name then you will see option to that related app.

Answer (score 14):

Your drafts and published apps are listed in the section `All applications`. When you click in one of them you are redirected to the `Dashboard` of that app. Because the app is a draft, for now you get some getting started tips, but later when it gets published you will have some useful plots. I guess the section you are looking for is **`Store listing`**, and you can access it in the sidebar. Before publishing the app you will also need to go over the remaining menus that have a check mark (`App releases`, `Content rating`, `Pricing & distribution`) and complete with the necessary information.

Answer (score 6):

You have to click in this area in order to edit the draft:

[image: You have to click in this area in order to edit the draft]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Short answers with (only) a URL are considered low quality because you answer will loose its usefulness if the url changes or breaks. Best practice is to include the key details in the text of your answer. See [answer] for more details.

Comment: Actually, that's the only correct answer to the original question and helped more than anything else.

Comment: This is the weirdest solution that I saw in Stackoverflow. It is worked by the way :) Strange UX design.

Comment: Agree that link has tendency to break, but you can always upload screen cap to SO. As an old saying goes...picture speaks a thousand words. :) The solution works for me as well

Answer (score 2):

I could resume my app name, description and screenshots upload by clicking
**Store presence / Main store listing** (under **Grow** in the left sidebar).

[image]